# Intrasolar planetary surface temperature change divergence from Earth

Tags: solar-system, planet, temperature, surface

Considering the vast amount of insulating gas emitted by human activity on Earth without a coincident release on all other planets in the solar system as well as the phenomenon that planets in a solar system normally exhibit similar coincident temperature changes described [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/1857/1098), how far have temperature changes diverged from Earth's?

Please include raw data, graphed if possible.

Comment: We've millions of raw temperature datapoints of Mars, a couple of Venus, some of other planets. But we've no detailed long-term climate data of other planets than Earth. For Earth we've e.g. polar ice cores from which long-term temperature fluctuations can be deduced. And we've climate observations over centuries on Earth, of gradually increasing quality. For other planets, this kind of research is still in its infancy. I doubt, that anyone can give you a fully satisfying answer to this question, at the moment.

Comment: The formula is based on a simplified theoretical model, which compares the inverse-square law (relative to the distance from the Sun) of incoming radiation with the grey body radiation of the planet (4th power law relative to the surface temperature of the planet, derived from Planck's law), more details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_temperature